# Using downloaded materials

Tags: materials

I know this question seems like it's answered elsewhere however I'm having difficulty :
I have downloaded some blender material files and I have followed all instructions I can see such as :
Going to file, appending material to current project, going to a specific object panel, selecting the new material (let's say a brick one for this case.)
All it does is shade the object black.
I unchecked the "use nodes" button. However if I don't use th nodes the material stays a solid colour.
I have unchecked the "use nodes" and attempted to paint with the new material but it just appears one solid colour (yes I check in the rendered scene as well)
I'm missing something obvious I'm sure but I'm not seeing any other instructions anywhere or anything obvious.. Please help!

Comment: Material or texture?

Comment: Welcome the Blender SE. One of a number of problems could be the cause. You can upload a sample of your file for people to look at in order to get an accurate idea of the trouble: you can upload your scene file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ .It could be as simple as using the wrong render engine or viewing it in a render mode unfamiliar to you.

Comment: Black shading could simply mean you are appending cycles materials into a blender internal scene or vice versa, or that a material output node is not connected to the rest of the node tree if you are using cycles, or the incorrect output is being used (surface output for volume shader for example). Without more clear information (images, simplified as much as possible sample file, ect as an [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/106692/edit) to your question) people will have to guess in order to try and help you.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.